# How to switch desktop to the next one like { win+ctrl+ ->} in win10?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-virtual-desktop

I learn some API form here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopsa  and [access violation when switching desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011641/access-violation-when-switching-desktops)

I know how to create a virtual desktop,like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

However, I want to go to the next desktop, like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd>, go to desktop1 or desktop2.
I know here is an API `BOOL SwitchDesktop([in] HDESK hDesktop);`, but I don't know how to get HDESK of desktop2, 3, 4.

Is there an API like `switchToNextDesktop`, `swithToLeftDesktop` and `switchToRightDesktop`?

Is there an API that can let me know the HDESK of desktop2, 3, 4, 5? The desktop2, 3, 4, 5 is created by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Maybe C# has some function? What about C++?

Comment: I believe you're talking about the "virtual desktop" API which is a different API (Windows Shell) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager

Comment: [Windows 10 virtual desktops are a window management feature, not a security feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180501-00/?p=98645).